# How do I get a gradient over my image? (link)

Tags: html, css, gradient

Everything should be explained in this jsfiddle.

***Im so sorry, but I can't get the link to show. Its in the comments!***

I can't get it to give me a red gradient over the image..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/s2moc0gt/2/

Comment: It won't let you paste the JSFiddle because there's no code here. Please post your relevant code in the question body and the link will work.

Comment: can you change the HTML?  say, by having a wrapper div right around the image?

Comment: A wrapper on the image **will** be required.

Comment: I have a wrapper, but still not working.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a wrapper around the image, but here is an example of how to set that up:

```css
.imgWrap {position:relative; display:inline-block;}
.imgWrap img {display:block;}
.imgWrap:after {content:""; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0; background:linear-gradient(transparent, red);}
.imgWrap:hover:after {display:none;}
```

```html
<div class="imgWrap">
 <img src="https://rocket-league.com//content/media/items/avatar/220px/75e8bb7e5d1473412157.png" />
</div>
```